# Android App NOT Running on Emulator, but on real device

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-emulator, crash

Android Studio 2.1, Gradle 2.1.0

I've search similar problem here, but nothing found. Mostly related to, the emulator is good but not on real device.

The problem is, once the emulator is ready and the app is launched, the app suddenly crashed as I click on first activity. Then, I tried to run on real device and everything works as it should be.

> 1st. This issue is not the same as App `running on emulator but not on
>   real device`, it's backward with this one.
>
> 2nd. No errors  in editor, just a little warning.
>
> 3rd. The logcats says; FATAL EXCEPTION: main.

What I've done;

> 1) Delete the current emulator only, without the system images.
>
> 2) Recreated the emulator, trying to launch the app, again, the app
>   crashed.
>
> 3) Delete, re-download all 3 system images;
>
> ARM EABI v7a System Image.
>
> Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image.
>
> Intel x86 Atom System Image.

Crash Report;

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                            Process: com.example.akmalzaki.uniklattendanceapp2, PID: 2942
>                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.akmalzaki.uniklattendanceapp2/com.example.akmalzaki.uniklattendanceapp2.Science}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.nfc.NfcAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'boolean android.nfc.NfcAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.akmalzaki.uniklattendanceapp2.Science.onCreate(Science.java:49)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: You should include your crash log

Comment: @DavidMedenjak already included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to get an NFC which emulator does not support. This may cause problems because there are still real devices in the world that dont have an NFC hardware. If it is critical to your application you should include manifest tag

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

This way the devices with no NFC support will not be able to install your application. If it is not critical, for example you have both NFC and QR Scan enabled, you can set this to `false` but you should very carefully check every method that asks NFCAdapter like this for example:

```
NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context) !=null
```

Comment: So the only way to this is just run it in the real device?

Comment: yes it is. Also you should always check for a null to avoid crashes

Comment: you know Everytime when we wanna do something such as open up a link, with multiple type of browsers installed, of course our phone will prompt a suggestions of which browsers we wanna use. Do you know how to make the app the I'm developing, been detected like that?

Comment: @InfiniteLoops of course, you just need to declare intent-filters in your manifest to catch default Intent actions